# SwiftUI: onChange with @Binding from outside view

Tags: swift, swiftui, onchange

**Updated to provide full reproducible example.**

I have a view `MainView` with two sub-views, `MainTextView` and `TableOfContentsView`. I want to select an item in `TableOfContentsView` which triggers a scroll position change in `MainTextView`.

I have an `@State var scrollPosition: Int` in `MainView` which is passed to an `@Binding var scrollPosition: Int` in `MainTextView`. Here is the code for my 3 views.

```swift
struct MainView: View {

    @State private var showingToc = false
    @State private var scrollPosition = 0

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Text("Table of Contents (chapter \(scrollPosition + 1))")
                .onTapGesture {
                    showingToc = !showingToc
                }

            Divider()

            if showingToc {
                TableOfContentsView(
                    onChapterSelected: { chapter in
                        scrollPosition = chapter
                        showingToc = false
                    }
                )
            } else {
                MainTextView(scrollPosition: $scrollPosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TableOfContentsView: View {

    var onChapterSelected: (Int) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 20) { i in
                    Text("Chapter \(i + 1)")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        onChapterSelected(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MainTextView: View {
    
    let lorumIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

    @Binding var scrollPosition: Int
    @State private var scrollProxy: ScrollViewProxy? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 20) { i in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Text("Chapter \(i + 1)")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                                .padding(.top)

                            Text(lorumIpsum)
                                .font(.system(size: 18, design: .serif))
                                .padding(.top)
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        .id(i)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.trailing)
                .onAppear {
                    scrollProxy = proxy
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scrollPosition) { target in
            scrollProxy?.scrollTo(target, anchor: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

My `.onChange` function is never called - if I place a breakpoint inside, it never hits the breakpoint. What am I missing here? How do I observe an `@Binding` that is changed from outside of the view?

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example

Comment: This Method  ----
onChange(of: scrollPosition) { target in
            proxy.scrollTo(target, anchor: .top)
        }
in MainTextView will be triggered when scroll position will be changed.
Use proxy.scrollTo outside this block.

Comment: Updated to provide reproducible example

Comment: @MattRobertson The reproducible example scrolls as expected. Are you running on a device/simulator or using Swift previews? Note that breakpoint support was removed from Swift previews in a recent Xcode update. Besides breakpoints, is there some other behaviour you're expecting?

Comment: @mani I am running on an iPhone 13 simulator. When I select a new chapter, the Binding value updates but the scroll position doesn’t change, and if I place a breakpoint on the line that calls for the scroll position change, it is never reached.

Comment: @MattRobertson see updated answer below - `MainTextView` doesn't exist while TOC is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.onChange` is not going to get called cause `MainTextView` doesn't exist when `showingToc = true` because of the conditional block:

```
if showingToc {
  TableOfContentsView(onChapterSelected: { chapter in
      scrollPosition = chapter
      showingToc = false
    }
  )
} else {
  MainTextView(scrollPosition: $scrollPosition)
}
```

You might want to consider showing TOC as an overlay. But to get your current code working, you need to call `proxy.scrollTo` in your `.onAppear` of `MainTextView`:

```
.onAppear {
  scrollProxy = proxy
  scrollProxy?.scrollTo(scrollPosition, anchor: .top)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did have this though. I've updated my OP to provide a full working example, showing that the `.onChange` is never called.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks. I'm used to Jetpack Compose on Android and am just learning SwiftUI. This is an interesting difference between the pure functional approach of Compose and the struct-based approach of SwiftUI.

Comment: I haven't any experience with Jetpack Compose - but I wonder what happens if you keep a instance of `MainTextView` as a member and always reuse the same instance. Or you can place `TableOfContentsView` above `MainTextView` in a `ZStack`.

Comment: Yeah I ended up going with the ZStack approach. Thanks for the suggestion!